# Stripe Token not generating

Tags: javascript, html, django, stripe-payments

I am designing Stripe based Payment gateway with all **CardNumber**, **CVC** and **Expiry** as different elements in django.

`payment.html (html part):`

```
           <div class="form-group">
             <label for="cardnumber">Credit or debit card:</label>
             <div id="cardnumber"></div>
           </div>

           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cardexpiry">Expiry:</label>
                    <div id="cardexpiry"></div>
                 </div>
               </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cardcvc">CVC:</label>
                    <div id="cardcvc"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

`payment.html (style part):`

```
  <style media="screen">
    .green{
      border : solid green 1px;
    }
    .error{
      border : solid red 1px;
    }
    .form-control::-moz-placeholder{
      color: #aab7c4;
    }
    </style>
```

`payment.html (script part):`

```
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_nnGYKgpxl7AmicqNbcoGIMqQ008d6IpXgw');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var cardnumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {
    classes : {
      base : "form-control",
      focus : "green",
      invalid : "error",
    },
    style : style
  });

    var cvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {
    classes : {
      base : "form-control",
      focus : "green",
      invalid : "error",
    },
    style : style
  });

    var exp = elements.create('cardExpiry',{
        classes : {
          base: "form-control",
          invalid : "error",
        },
      style : style
    });
  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  cardnumber.mount('#cardnumber');
  cvc.mount('#cardcvc');
  exp.mount('#cardexpiry');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  cardnumber.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  cvc.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  exp.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });


  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(cardnumber.then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  // Submit the form with the token ID.
  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }
```

I am trying to create token using all the elements. I have gone through some of the answers to tokenize using all the elements and as per the answers, I am using only one element **cardnumer** for tokenization. But it seems it is not generating the token.

This script is not printing token when I am trying to print **request.POST**.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: hmm, `stripe.createToken(cardnumber.then(function(result) {...})` looks wrong, maybe it should be `stripe.createToken(cardnumber).then(function(result) {...})` ? (note the `)` to close the call to createToken.

Comment: But I am facing a new issue now. I am creating a customer using ```stripe.Customer.create(
   name = request.POST['name'],
   email = request.POST['email'],
   address = request.POST['address'],
   source = request.POST['stripeToken']
   )```  in my views.py and I got the error as: ``Request req_vL0Z2mkBIrhu7N: Invalid object`` by pointing at ``source=request.POST['stripeToken]``. How can it be resolved?